# querySelectorAll selection based on css

Tags: javascript, html, css, selector

here's a simple representation of a problem I have. When you click on the button, all black divs should change to black. But the big one styled with css doesn't. Any ideas? thanks a lot.

```js
var v;

function link() {
  v = document.querySelectorAll('[style*="background:black;"]');
  v.forEach(function(value) {
    value.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  });
}
```

```css
.box1 {
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="filter.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div style="background:black; height:100px; width:100px;" id="div1"></div>
  <div style="background:blue; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
  <div style="background:black; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
  <div class="box1"> css styled box</div>
  <button onclick="link()" style="height:20px; width:50px;">Click </button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you want the big black one to become red as well?

Comment: Well, that should not come unexpected at all - you have a queryselector that explicitly only selects elements with `style="background-color..."`. **There is no CSS selector where you can select elements based on their current styling.** You need to know what you are doing. Also, **never** use inline styles except for quick testing purposes.

Comment: @Phanti Yes I do want to get the black one to get red as well, but I would like to learn **how to select it based on the css and not the style.**

Comment: @connexo thanks, I am kinda new to js so I am happy to learn this

Comment: You can't select html items based on their corresponding css. Have a look into  jQuery selectors which is a great library for such topics: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ meanwhile use the solution suggested from @par tha

Comment: You shouldn't be doing almost anything that you are demonstrating here in the first place.

Comment: @Phanti jQuery for a beginner in 2019 ***is imo really bad advice***.

Comment: "When you click on the button, all black divs should change to black." ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
var v;
function link(){
 v=document.querySelectorAll('[style*="background:black;"]');
 v.forEach(function(value){
  value.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 });
}
```

```css
.box1{
 height:200px;
 width:200px;
 border:2px solid green;
    font-size:25px;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="filter.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div style="background:black; height:100px; width:100px;" id="div1"></div>
<div style="background:blue; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div style="background:black; height:100px; width:100px;"></div>
<div class="box1" style="background:black;"> css styled box</div>
<button onclick="link()" style="height:20px; width:50px;">Click </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if they have a `background-color` defined in `.box1`, other than `black`, and they don't want it overridden?